# Sample variance derivation

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

I have quite a simple question but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

For a set of iid samples $\,\,X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n\,\,$ from distribution with mean $\,\mu$.

If you are given the sample variance as

$$ S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)^2 $$

How can you write the following?

$$ S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \mu\right)^2 - n\left(\mu - \bar{X}\right)^2\right] $$

All texts that cover this just skip the details but I can't work it out myself. I get stuck after expanding like so

$$ S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(X_i^2 -2X_i\bar{X} + \bar{X}^2\right) $$

What am I missing?

**Edit:**
A similarly equivalent expression is often given that I also can't derive but which may be more obvious is

$$  S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - n\bar{X}^2\right] $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \mu\right)^2 - 
n\left(\mu - \bar{X}\right)^2\right]
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left[\left(X_i - \mu\right)^2 - 
\left(\mu - \bar{X}\right)^2\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)
\left(X_i + \bar{X} - 2\mu\right).\end{align*}$$
Now, 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}) = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \bar{X}
= n\bar{X} - n\bar{X}= 0 $$
and so
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)
\left(X_i + \bar{X} - 2\mu\right) 
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)X_i 
+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)\left(\bar{X} - 2\mu\right)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)X_i 
+ \left(\bar{X} - 2\mu\right)\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)
\right]\\
&=  \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)X_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)X_i
- \bar{X}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)\right]\\
&=  \frac{1}{n-1}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_i - \bar{X}\right)^2\\
&= S^2 
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Crystal clear, thank you. (I'm a little bit surprised that this is often assumed obvious because it isn't to me)

Comment: @Chris If you liked Dilip's answer (I know I did) then it'd be nice if you upvote it and, perhaps, accept it as best answer, though you can wait for this last some time in case other answers pop up

Comment: @Don: Note that the OP cannot yet upvote until someone else upvotes his question so that he has at least 15 rep.

Answer (score 2):

$$S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu +\mu-\bar X)^2$$

$$=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\mu)^2 +2(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\bar X)+(\mu-\bar X)^2]$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2 +2\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)(\mu-\bar X)+\sum_{i=1}^n(\mu-\bar X)^2]$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2 +2n\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{X_i}{n}-\frac{\mu}{n})(\mu-\bar X)+\sum_{i=1}^n(\mu-\bar X)^2]$$
$$=\frac{1}{n-1}[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2 -2n(\mu-\bar X)(\mu-\bar X)+n(\mu-\bar X)^2]$$

Let me add that replace $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$  by  $\bar X$ in the last but one line. and flip it around to get the negative sign.

Comment: *The middle term gives zero. Hence the result.* Hmm...

Comment: I guess then, my trouble is understanding why the middle term is zero. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Chris: It's not zero, hence, my comment.

Comment: I have seen my mistake. I will fix it.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely need to get better at manipulating expressions inside summations.

Comment: @Chris. I think this should fix it. I am not so sure if my manipulation is right, but surely you can follow through.